# extracting specific characters from middle of the string in a long text data in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, text

I am stucked at a problem where I have to extract some characters from the string .

```
data 

['  10001296        58.38525-26.136000003431            348.         0         0\n',
 '  10001297          58.975-26.400000003465            344.         0         0\n',
 '  10001298          58.975-26.400000003465            340.         0         0\n',
 '  10001299          58.975-26.400000003465            336.         0         0\n',
 '  10001300          58.975-26.400000003465            332.         0         0\n',
 '  10001301          58.975-26.400000003465            328.         0         0\n',
 '  10001302          58.975-26.400000003465            324.         0         0\n',
 '  10001303          58.975-26.400000003465            320.         0         0\n']
```

From above data, I want to extract the **character number 11 to 36** from each line and want to store in a list. How can I do that?? In above example, the characters I want to achive is          `58.38525` and similary in other lines below also.

I know how to extract the first 10 characters. But I do not know how to achieve characters from the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
data = [
    "  10001296        58.38525-26.136000003431            348.         0         0\n",
    "  10001297          58.975-26.400000003465            344.         0         0\n",
    "  10001298          58.975-26.400000003465            340.         0         0\n",
    "  10001299          58.975-26.400000003465            336.         0         0\n",
    "  10001300          58.975-26.400000003465            332.         0         0\n",
    "  10001301          58.975-26.400000003465            328.         0         0\n",
    "  10001302          58.975-26.400000003465            324.         0         0\n",
    "  10001303          58.975-26.400000003465            320.         0         0\n",
]

out = [line[11:36].strip() for line in data]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "58.38525-26.136000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
    "58.975-26.400000",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty basic use of string manipulations:

> data[0][11:36]

Will give what you want for 1st line.

If you want for each line, make a loop over:

> data[i][11:36]